# filtering or subsetting a dataframe using multiple columns matching values in a list

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to select a subset of rows from a dataframe using the
values stored in a list. Subsetting a dataframe is a common topic (e.g.
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239194/subset-row-in-dataframe-by-values) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244217/subset-dataframe-by-multiple-logical-conditions-of-rows-to-remove)),
but in all those questions the values are known prior to runtime. I want
to use a named list generated in a shiny app to pick out rows and
display them in a datatable object. I'll use `dplyr::filter()` but I
think the same idea should work with `subset()` or `[]`.

```r
library(dplyr) 
data("mtcars")

# get all 6 cylinder cars with 3 gears 
filter(mtcars, cyl == 6 & gear == 3)
#>    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> 2 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

So far so good, but I have those values in a named list.

```r
pickthese <- list(cyl = 6, gear = 3)
```

I've tried variations of `paste()` with `parse()` and `eval()`, and this
works but seems clumsy.

```r
eval(
  parse(
    text = paste("filter(mtcars, ",
                 paste(paste0(names(pickthese)[1]," == ", pickthese[[1]]),
                       paste0(names(pickthese)[2]," == ", pickthese[[2]]), sep = ","),
                 ")")))
#>    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> 2 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

I could turn the inner `paste0()` into a function and use `*apply()` or
`purrr::map` to simplify some. Is there a better solution?

EDIT:

r2evans brought up a good point about what happens if the user screws up. I could think of two possible ways for this -- first, the user could select a value not in the dataframe, and second, the user could select a variable name not found in the dataframe. The second case *shouldn't* happen because the variable names in the app are set by me, but I'm not immune to screwing up either! I think the solution should either return a zero row data frame with the same columns (in first case), or cause an error.

```r
# test case
lst <- list(cyl = 6.2, gear = 3, foo = "bar")
```

Created on
2018-07-17 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org)
(v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create an expression that can be parsed

```
expr <- do.call(paste, c(stack(pickthese)[2:1], sep="==", collapse=";"))
```

or create with `tidyverse`

```
expr <- enframe(pickthese) %>% 
                unnest %>%
                reduce(paste, sep="==", collapse=";")


mtcars %>% 
    filter(!!! rlang::parse_exprs(expr))
#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#2 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Answer (score 2):

More options, no `parse`ing required.

```
lst <- list(cyl=6, gear=3)

df1 <- as.data.frame(lst)
mtcars %>% inner_join(df1)
# Joining, by = c("cyl", "gear")
#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# 2 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

nlst <- paste(names(lst), lst, sep="==")
mtcars %>% filter_(.dots=nlst)
#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# 2 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I learned a great deal from your answer. I like the construction of `nlst` very much, but didn't accept this answer b/c `filter_()` is deprecated.

Comment: Your call! I find using `parse` user-generated code in almost every situation to be a fragile side-step around missing functionality. Glad I could help.

Comment: and what was wrong with `inner_join` @atiretoo ? It's much cleaner, if you have some edge case in mind maybe you could share it ?

Comment: I forgot about `inner_join()` actually -- I'm about to go back and test all of the answers against a possible issue of no matches and see if that differentiates them at all.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest is base `R`:

```
l <- list(cyl = 6, gear = 3)
merge(mtcars,l)
#   cyl gear  mpg disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am carb
# 1   6    3 18.1  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    1
# 2   6    3 21.4  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    1
```

With `dplyr` we need first to convert your list to a `tibble` / `data.frame` and join it to the table with `right_join` or `inner_join` and we end up with @r2evans' solution.

Alternatively if we really want to filter, we can use `filter_at` with `reduce` :

```
library(tidyverse) # for dplyr and purrr
reduce(imap(l,~setNames(.x,.y)),
  ~filter_at(.x, names(.y),all_vars(.== .y)),
  .init=mtcars)
#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# 2 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: Yah, I'm coming around to the inner_join() / merge() position. merge() starts by doing as.data.frame() on the list, so not much difference there!

Comment: well, just 3 times shorter and no extra package;)

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could accept 3 answers! I'm learning so much here. I will combine bits of each of the above answers to get what I want in a very clear way.

```r
nlst <- paste(names(pickthese), pickthese, sep="==") # from r2evans

mtcars %>% filter(!!! rlang::parse_exprs(nlst)) # from akrun

#>    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> 2 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

I'm going to stick with this despite the concern about parsing, and also because of an issue with the `merge()` or `inner_join()` approach. All of the solutions work as expected if the value is not found in the data, returning zero row dataframes.

They do perform differently on the second issue, if the variable name is not part of the dataframe. Using `merge()` or `inner_join()` the erroneous variable name is added as a new column, even in a zero row dataframe. I just noticed another thing with `merge()` -- doesn't preserve the row or column order in the result. That wouldn't matter sometimes, but it does in this case because the result would display differently if I select different variables, and that would get annoying at least.

```r
lst <- list(cyl = 6, gear = 3, foo = "bar") # 2nd problem

merge(mtcars, lst) # two rows, but silently adds column foo
#>   cyl gear  mpg disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am carb foo
#> 1   6    3 18.1  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    1 bar
#> 2   6    3 21.4  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    1 bar

inner_join(mtcars, as.data.frame(lst)) # two rows and silently adds column foo
#> Joining, by = c("cyl", "gear")
#>    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb foo
#> 1 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 bar
#> 2 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 bar

nlst <- paste(names(lst), lst, sep="==")
mtcars %>% filter(!!! rlang::parse_exprs(nlst)) # error -- tells me I screwed up the programming.
#> Error in filter_impl(.data, quo): Evaluation error: object 'foo' not found.
```

Annnd, one more addition. `semi_join()` as suggested below is the winner in my actual use case, as something about the actual data.frame breaks the parsing solution that works here - I think it is character variables.

Comment: I understand your point, FYI you can use `semi_join(mtcars, as.data.frame(lst)) ` and the additional variable won't appear in the result, but it won't trigger an error. One possibility would be to add `stopifnot(all(names(lst) %in% names(mtcars))`, note that if foo actually exist the error becomes `Error: `x` must be a string or a R connection` which is not so readable